# Server Error in '/' Application. Could not load type 'Tracker.DAL.TrackerModel'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

Longtime reader, first time questioning. I've started to adapt the Contoso Uni sample, and I get this error when trying to 'add' a new 'client':

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not load type 'Tracker.DAL.TrackerModel'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the c0de.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Could not load type 'Tracker.DAL.TrackerModel'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

CODE:

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ClientDetails.aspx.cs" Inherits="Tracker.ClientDetails" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h3>Client Details</h3>
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ContextTypeName="Tracker.DAL.TrackerModel" EnableFlattening="False"  
        EntitySetName="Clients" EnableDelete="True"  EnableInsert="True" ConnectionString="name=TrackerModelContainer" DefaultContainerName="TrackerModelContainer" >
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
    <asp:DetailsView ID="ClientDetailsView" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="ClientId" 
        DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" DefaultMode="Insert" oniteminserting="ClientDetailsView_ItemInserting">
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Alias" HeaderText="Alias" SortExpression="Alias" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Suburb" HeaderText="Suburb" SortExpression="Suburb" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State" SortExpression="State" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Postcode" HeaderText="Postcode" SortExpression="Postcode" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Telephone" HeaderText="Telephone" SortExpression="Telephone" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Managing Office"> 
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=TrackerModelContainer"
                        DefaultContainerName="TrackerModelContainer" EnableDelete="True" EnableFlattening="False" 
                        EntitySetName="Offices" >
                    </asp:EntityDataSource> 
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="OfficeLocationDropDownList" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1"
                             DataTextField="OfficeLocation" DataValueField="OfficeId"
                             oninit="OfficeLocationDropDownList_Init">
                        </asp:DropDownList>       
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowInsertButton="True" />
           
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
</asp:Content>
```

As a novice, any help appreciated.